# Numba JIT on static method works on one computer but throws an error on another

Tags: python, numba

I have a static method that I want to speed up with Numba:

```
@nb.njit
def numba_loop_choice(population, weights, k):
    wc = np.cumsum(weights)
    m = wc[-1]
    sample = np.empty(k, population.dtype)
    sample_idx = np.full(k, -1, np.int32)
    i = 0
    while i < k:
        r = m * np.random.rand()
        idx = np.searchsorted(wc, r, side="right")
        if idx in sample_idx[:i]:
            continue
        sample[i] = population[idx]
        sample_idx[i] = idx
        i += 1
    return sample
```

population and weights are numpy arrays, k is an integer.
If I run this on my home computer it works without any error. On my server it crashes with an error. Both have Python 3.8.10. Does anyone understand why it works on one machine but crashes on another?

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                       
  File "run.py", line 115, in <module>                                                                                                                   
    paa.simulate_streams()                                                                                                                               
  File "run.py", line 40, in simulate_streams                                                                                                            
    StreamSimulation(                                                                                                                                    
  File "xxx/simulate_stream.py", line 63, in __init__                                                                       
    self.simulate()                                                                                                                                      
  File "xxx/simulate_stream.py", line 132, in simulate                                                                      
    selected_element = numba_loop_choice(population=elements_dummy[0:latest_element + 1], weights=self.weights[0:latest_element + 1], k=1)[0]            
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 401, in _compile_for_args                                                              
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')                                                                                                                           
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 344, in error_rewrite                                                                  
    reraise(type(e), e, None)                                                                                                                            
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/six.py", line 668, in reraise                                                                               
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)                                          
numba.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)                                                                     
Invalid use of Function(<built-in function contains>) with argument(s) of type(s): (array(int32, 1d, C), int64)                                          
 * parameterized                      
In definition 0:                      
    All templates rejected with literals.                                   
In definition 1:                      
    All templates rejected without literals.                                
In definition 2:                      
    All templates rejected with literals.                                   
In definition 3:                      
    All templates rejected without literals.                                
In definition 4:                      
    All templates rejected with literals.
    All templates rejected with literals.                                   
In definition 5:                      
    All templates rejected without literals.                                
In definition 6:                      
    All templates rejected with literals.                                   
In definition 7:                      
    All templates rejected without literals.                                
In definition 8:                      
    All templates rejected with literals.                                   
In definition 9:                      
    All templates rejected without literals.                                
In definition 10:                     
    All templates rejected with literals.                                   
In definition 11:                     
    All templates rejected without literals.                                
In definition 12:                     
    All templates rejected with literals.                                   
In definition 13:                     
    All templates rejected without literals.                                
This error is usually caused by passing an argument of a type that is unsupported by the named function.                                                 
[1] During: typing of intrinsic-call at xxx/simulate_stream.py (24)

File "simulate_stream.py", line 24:
def numba_loop_choice(population, weights, k):
    <source elided>
        print(idx, sample_idx)
        if idx in sample_idx[:i]:
        ^
```

Comment: Numba functions are lazily compiled by default unless you provide the types (which is not the case here). This means the function is compiled based on the argument during the first call. Since the arguments are not provided here, we cannot reproduce the problem. Please provide them. Besides, can you check the version of Numba (and possibly the one of Numpy)? I might be a bug that has been solved in a new version or a regression. Please also mention the target OS of the two machines.

Comment: indeed, upgrading both numpy and numba with `pip install <package_name> --upgrade` fixed the issue. Thank you for the help!